# how do i get rid of space on the left side of the slideshow

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I have got this space on the left side of my slideshow i have tried getting rid of it by using padding:0px and margin:0px but it kind of makes more mess

can anyone help me please here is the link to the site

http://goo.gl/aS3y1

Comment: try to click to the menu items with the solution implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="slideshow">
<ul id="slides" style="overflow: hidden;">
<li id="content" style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 29;">
<li style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 30; right: 0px;">
<img src="http://www.pdqmachine.biz/_images/uploads/slide1.jpg" alt="Sea turtle">
</li>
<li style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 31; right: 0px;">
<img src="http://www.pdqmachine.biz/_images/uploads/slide2.jpg" alt="Coral Reef">
</li>
<li style="position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 28; right: 0px;">
</ul>
</div>
```

i have added `right:0px` to the li

Comment: this answer was picked but try to click to the menu items

Comment: try my solution, solves that too the clear:both, he have more styles to look at :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `#slides`

```
#slides {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 950px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#slideshow {
        height: 240px;

        margin-left: -40px;
        position: relative;
        width: 950px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the style in the #main2 and this will solve you more issues :) because you have float in previous DIV and your slider is above the menu and you will be unable to click the items.

```
#main2 { 
 ....
 clear:both; 
}
```

and in

```
#slides {
   float: left;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quickfix

```
ul#slides {
    margin-left:-37px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.column-inmiddle {
    width: 138%; remove this or make 100%
}

#slideshow {
    position: relative;
    width: 950px;
    height: 240px;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto; add this
}
```

hopefully you'll get what u want